# OS X: How to retain controller using ARC and block-based sheet APIs?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, nswindow

On OS X 10.9 there is a new block-based method for sheet presentation:

```
    [window beginSheet:[myWindowController window] 
        completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
            NSLog(@"done");
    }
    ];
```

The problem is that `myWindowController` is deallocated immediately if it isn't referenced in the completion block. This causes a crash when its window is dismissed. When using ARC, how can I ensure the sheet's window controller lives through the modal session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally did this as a comment but I'll make this as an answer:

You should assign "`myWindowController`" to a strong property in whatever object (NSWindowController or whatever) that brings up the sheet.

E.G., use

```
@property (strong) NSWindowController *mySpecialSheet;
```

Comment: What if the lifecycle of `myWindowController` need only last as long as its window (the sheet)? For instance, when the user presses a button, the sheet appears, user interacts with the sheet, and the sheet is closed. The sheet's controller only exists to facilitate logic for the sheet. In my view the controller should be properly deallocated once it's done with, so an ivar in another controller is not a good spot for the storage.

Comment: Your sheet is hanging off some parent window, right?  Keeping it around with a strong property on that parent window is the most straightforward solution.  You could instead have an always-existing singleton to store your "`myWindowController`" object.